# Divergence case comparison test $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1}dx$. Show it converges or diverges.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1}dx$

I cant integrate this so I try comparison test:

For $x \in [0, \infty), f(x) = \frac{cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \geq 0$

For $x \in [0, \infty), f(x) = \frac{cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \geq \frac{?}{\sqrt{x}}$

I have no idea how to get a good comparison to show this integral diverges. I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} dx$ diverges. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $\le$ for the second item?

Comment: for divergence i gotta show a lesser func i think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is continuous and integrable over $[0,1]$.  To show divergence, consider

$$\int_1^c \frac{\cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \,dx$$.

Using the identity $\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2x -1$ we have

$$\int_1^c \frac{\cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^c \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \,dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_1^c \frac{\cos^(6x+2)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \,dx.$$

The first integral on the RHS diverges as $c \to \infty$ since $1 \ (\sqrt{x} +1 ) \geqslant 1/(2\sqrt{x})$ for $x \geqslant 1$.  Using either integration by parts or the Dirichlet test we can see that the second integral converges. Thus, the integral on the LHS diverges.

Comment: This question is way more complicated than all the other questions in my textbook. Thx I got what you did.

Comment: You're welcome.  I used this approach because at least part directly involved the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{2n\pi/3}^{2(n+1)\pi/3} \frac{\cos^2(3x+1)}{\sqrt{x}+1} \ge 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n+1)\pi/3}+1}\int_{2n\pi/3}^{2(n+1)\pi/3} \cos^2(3x+1)\; dx = \frac{\pi}{3 (\sqrt{2(n+1)\pi/3}+1)}$$
and the sum of the right side diverges by a comparison test.